# Swift: Creating a double from a String appends 0000000000001 to the resulting number

Tags: ios, string, swift, casting, double

I am trying to get a `Double` value from a `UITextField` using `Double(myTextField.text!)!`. The problem is, when I enter certain numbers I get **0000000000001** appended to the end of the number. For example, `Double("9.05")!` gives the value `9.050000000000001` instead of the expected `9.05`.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how I get avoid / fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Explanations: http://floating-point-gui.de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a general problem of binary representations of a floating point digits where 9.05 cannot be represented exactly.

Try this in a playground:

```
9.05 // 9.050000000000001
```

so even directly initializing the value is not a "workaround"

Answer (score 6):

As several have noted, the underlying problem is that when you store 9.05 in binary, you get rounding errors. So it's not appending some value; it's showing you the correct value after rounding (in binary). This is very much like store 2/3 in decimal. You wind up with "6.66667" which seems wrong, but is due to rounding. 1/100 is "0.00000010100011110101..." in binary.

To get what you want, you need formatting. Ashish gives a working example, but it's become easier in more recent builds of Swift. You don't need `as NSString` anymore:

```
import Foundation
let strVal = "9.05"
let doubleVal = Double(strVal)! // Convert String to Double
let formattedStr = String(format: "%.2f", doubleVal) // Double -> String w/ formatting
print(formattedStr)
```

You may be confused about the difference between the double value and how it is represented as decimal digits. You can't express 9.05 in a finite number of binary digits, just like you can't express 2/3 in a finite number of decimal digits. There will always be some rounding error. That's why, for instance, you cannot safely compare with `==` two floating point numbers.

If what you really want is to do decimal math, then you have two choices:

- Work in fixed point rather than floating point. Multiply everything by 100 and store it as an `Int`. For many problems is this an ideal solution.
- `NSDecimalNumber`. This is available in Cocoa and lets you do math in decimal rather than binary. 9.05 as an `NSDecimalNumber` is exactly 9.05. This is a good solution for more general problems, but is a little harder to implement.

Comment: Just a note: `Double(strVal)` comes with Swift 2.0, doesn't work with older builds.

Comment: Thanks; I thought it was 1.2, but I hadn't checked.

Answer (score 1):

As Eric D. Defined in comment please check the http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

You can format your string to get desired output :

```
var strVal = "9.05"
var dbl : Double = (NSString(format: "%.2f", (strVal as NSString).doubleValue)).doubleValue
println(dbl)
```

It's working in **Xcode Version 6.3.2**

Comment: I need the value as a `Double`, not a `String` (or `NSString`).

Comment: That gets me back to the original `9.050000000000001`

Comment: @BenjyWiener please check the updated answer. I have checked. it gives me 9.05. Hope you are printing old output

Answer (score 1):

try use this

```
var value: Double = (swiftString as NSString).doubleValue
```

see:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/doubleValue